# Suspected overlapping tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags, named [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs), and [aws-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ecs). Is there a difference between them, if any? To which one of these do I need to post?

Comment: [tag:ecs] and [tag:aws-ecs] are [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-ecs/synonyms) to [tag:amazon-ecs].

Comment: @honk then aren't they supposed to have the same number of question/watchers?

Comment: @Uberhumus They likely don't because the tags aren't _merged_ yet, so any questions that had aws-ecs before the synonym was made may still have that tag. (From my understanding, I could be totally way off here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't 2 tags.  There is only 1 tag ([amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs)) and the other is a synonym of it.  So that means if someone adds [aws-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ecs) as a new tag on a question, it will be automatically changed to [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs).  But because of the way the tags work, you may still see [aws-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ecs) on questions, but for purposes of searching, it will behave like [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs).

Here's the synonym page for it (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-ecs/synonyms), so you can see how it mentions that aws-ecs will be remapped to amazon-ecs

> [image]